# Django Rest Framework filtering data by url

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to filter my Django Rest Framework serialized data by the URL provided by user. Here is my code:

models.py:

```
class Airline(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class FinancialData(models.Model): 
    airline = models.ForeignKey(Airline)
    mainline_revenue = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    regional_revenue = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    other_revenue = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    total_revenue = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

        def __str__(self):
        return str(self.mainline_revenue)
```

view.py:

```
class ListAirlineFinancialData(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FinancialDataSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        query_list = FinancialData.objects.filter(pk=airline_id)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/v1/airline/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ListAirlineFinancialData.as_view(), name='airline_financial_data'),
]
```

What should I code in views to filter my data for the following URL.
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/airline/3/

At this moment Django is giving me an error that **name 'airline_id' is not defined** I can understand that it wants me to pass on airline_id which is in my database but I really dont know how to do it. What code should I write in views.py that it filters all the data for the airline any particular id. Thanks

Comment: You need to add a RetrieveAPIView along with LIstAPIView. May be this will help you  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview

Answer (score 6):

Your solution approach is correct. However your code seems ambiguous for readers.

For eg: If you are applying query on FinancialData then your url pattern should have financialdata in urlpath rather than airline. Also `<pk>` is generally used as primary key for the model you are applying query to and not for the foreign key on the model.

So `urlpattern` should be like

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^api/v1/financialdata/(?P<airline_pk>\d+)/$',
        views.ListAirlineFinancialData.as_view(),
        name='airline_financial_data'),
]
```

and url will be like: `/api/v1/financialdata/1/`

Also, it is a general practice to pass filter parameters as `query_params`. In that case your urlpattern will be

```
url(
        r'^api/v1/financialdata/$',
        views.ListAirlineFinancialData.as_view(),
        name='airline_financial_data'),
]
```

and your url will be like: `/api/v1/financialdata/?airline_pk=1`

In case of passing filter parameters as query_params, your `get_queryset` will be a little different:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.queryset.filter(airline_id=self.request.GET.get('airline_pk'))
```

Lastly, Django Rest Framework is very powerful yet simple in using. You can read more about filters on [Django Rest Framework Filtering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to figure out the solution after many hours of research. If anyone else come here for answer then I changed my views to following:

```
class ListFinancialData(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = FinancialData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FinancialDataSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.queryset.filter(airline_id=self.kwargs.get('airline_pk'))
```